# gdm-password conversation error occurs every 25 minutes without user attempting to login

Tags: centos, pam, gdm

I am running CentOS 6.6 and I trying to figure out what might be causing gdm-password error to show up every 25 minutes in /var/log/messages log eventhough no user has attempted to login. Can someone please help me to understand what might be running every 25 minutes that could cause this error to occur.

```
Aug 25 00:10:22 TEST pam: gdm-password: pam_succeed_if(gdm-password:auth): error retrieving user name: Conversation error
Aug 25 00:10:22 TEST pam: gdm-password: gkr-pam: couldn't get the user name: Conversation error
Aug 25 00:10:22 TEST pam: gdm-password: pam_succeed_if(gdm-password:auth): error retrieving user name: Conversation error
Aug 25 00:10:22 TEST pam: gdm-password: pam_selinux_permit(gdm-password:auth): Cannot determine the user's name
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to determine that the below gconf setting was causing the gdm password error to show up every 25 minutes.

```
gconftool-2 --direct --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory --set /desktop/gnome/session/max_idle_action --type string forced-logout
```

To Fix this I made sure the gconf setting was set as a regular user and not as root.

```
sudo -u username gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/session/max_idle_action --type string forced-logout
```